# Can I save rascal vis::Chart charts to files?

Tags: rascal

I've been trying out the chart module. I want to graph some simple data, in the REPL the standard example: `barChart([<"<x>",x> | x <- [1..100]])` works fine. However, when I put the same line of code in a module it executes but I don't see the chart anywhere.

I tried the `chartServer` but that doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The REPL has its own webserver that it hosts the `Content` servlets in, if they appear as results after a command. But that does not stop you from running the same servlets in another webserver:

1. `util::IDEServices` provides the `showInteractiveContent` function which mirrors the exact functionality that the REPL offers. This means that servlets will be garbage collected after 30 minutes of inactivity on the same port number, and that when new servlets are registered they may re-use previousely collected ports on localhost.
2. `util::Webserver` provides several functions to create and start a similar webserver based on the same `Content` values. Here you as a programmer are responsible for starting and stopping servers that you create.

The three scenerio's are all facades for the same HTTP server code, which wraps bridges between Rascal data-types and HTML5 data-types and HTTP requests and responses. So this means that the same code works in the same way, no matter which of the three ways you pick to serve the content.

The REPL and the IDEServices thus provide:

- automatic start and stop of HTTP server
- automatic use of the (internal) web browser of the IDE or the Desktop browser

The Webserver option provides:

- manual handling of HTTP ports
- no automatic browser opening

So for the latter you have to combine with features from `util::IDEServices` to show the content or not.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do the trick :)